# Custom shader not working on mobile phone (Unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, shader

I have a custom shader and it doesn't work on my mobile device but works on the PC. How do I convert it so it works on a mobile device?

Following is my code:

```
Shader "vertexPainter/DiffuseNormalSpec_2tex_mask" {
    Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex1 ("Base 1 (RGBA)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _BumpMap1 ("Bumpmap 1 (RGB)", 2D) = "bump" {}

    _MainTex2 ("Base 2 (RGB)", 2D) ="black" {}
    _BumpMap2 ("Bumpmap 2 (RGB)", 2D) = "bump" {}
    _BlendMask ("Blend Mask", 2D) = "white" {}

    _Shininess("shininess", Range(0,0.8)) = 0.1
    _SpecColor("spec color", Color) = (0,0,0,0)
    _BlendSoft("Blend Softness", Range(0,0.8)) = 0.1
    _B_Normal("B Normal", Range(0,0.8)) = 0.1
    }
    SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 600

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf BlinnPhong vertex:vert
    #pragma target 3.0
    struct Input {
    float2 uv_MainTex1 : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 uv2_BlendMask : TEXCOORD1;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    };
    void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input o) {
    UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o); 
    o.color = (v.color);
    }
    uniform sampler2D _MainTex1, _MainTex2, _BlendMask;
    uniform sampler2D _BumpMap1, _BumpMap2;
    half3 _SelfIllum;
    half _BlendSoft, _B_Normal;
    fixed _Shininess;
    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {

    half4 base = tex2D(_MainTex1, IN.uv_MainTex1);
    half4 blend1 = tex2D(_MainTex2, IN.uv_MainTex1);

    half4 blendmask = tex2D(_BlendMask, IN.uv2_BlendMask);
    half transformed = ((1 - IN.color.g) - blendmask.r)/_BlendSoft;

    half mask = saturate(transformed); 
    half4 finresult = lerp(blend1, base, mask); 
    half specresultg = lerp(blend1.a, base.a, mask); 

    half3 g_normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_BumpMap2, IN.uv_MainTex1));
    g_normal *= 1-(blendmask.b * _B_Normal);
    half3 r_normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_BumpMap1, IN.uv_MainTex1));
    half3 norresultg = lerp(g_normal, r_normal, mask); 

    o.Albedo = finresult.rgb;
    o.Normal = norresultg;
    o.Alpha = 1;
    o.Specular = _Shininess;
    o.Gloss = specresultg * _SpecColor;
    }
    ENDCG
    }

    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Screenshots for the shader:

This is what it looks like on my PC:

[image]

This is what it looks like on my mobile:

[image]

## Specifications

PC:
OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
Processor : Intel(r) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40 Ghz(8CPUs), ~3.4Ghz
Memory: 16,384MB RAM
Graphic Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960

Phone:
Samsung Galaxy s7 but right now i'm using an emulator(Bluestack)

Comment: can you check with adb logcat to see if its giving some errors in device:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/492681/how-to-use-adb-logcat.html

Comment: Hey, did you figure out what the issue was? I have a similar terrain blender shader and I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Go Settings -> Graphics, 
and 
add the shaders you need to the "Always Included Shaders" list.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on iPhone device and answer mentioned above didn't work for me. I solved my problem keeping one Quality settings for iOS and problem were that my URP had different settings for different qualities and keeping only one not only fixed my shader issue but is better for optimizing mobile game. You can check more optimization tips [here](https://blog.unity.com/technology/optimize-your-mobile-game-performance-expert-tips-on-graphics-and-assets).